# My for loop is taking too much time

Tags: php, json, loops, for-loop

These days, there is an election in Turkey and i am coding a php script to follow elections with an API and I have a for loop in my project to show general results of of all Turkey. This loop is summing up 81 different provinces results but it is taking too much time and sometimes it is not working because it takes more than 30 seconds and my page is not loading. What can I do to reduce this time?

```
$mi_total_vote = 0;

for ($id=1; $id < 82; $id++) {
  $turkey_data = file_get_contents('http://secim-api.adilsecim.net/2/city/'.$id.'.json');
  $turkey_json = json_decode($turkey_data);
  $mi = $turkey_json->results->mi;
  $mi_total_vote = $mi_total_vote + $mi;
}
```

JSON files are my API data. I have to sum up them to obtain the results for all Turkey.

Comment: There's little you can do to reduce the time it takes to make an HTTP request... Is there no way for you to get those results in a single file?

Comment: Sadly, there is no way to get them in a single file :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use cURL, it's faster:

```
<?php
    $mi_total_vote = 0;

    for ($id=1; $id < 82; $id++) {

       $ch =  curl_init('http://secim-api.adilsecim.net/2/city/1.json');
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
       $turkey_data = curl_exec($ch);  

       $turkey_json = json_decode($turkey_data);
       $mi = $turkey_json->results->mi;
       $mi_total_vote = $mi_total_vote + $mi;
    }


?>
```

Comment: that's not made a big difference :/

Comment: @cemekkazan to me it only took few seconds. try your code in http://phpfiddle.org/

Comment: @SupunPraneeth ye you right, took me 1.5s - but maybe his server has a limited connection

Comment: i think there is problem with cURL in my server

Comment: yes but i solved it but still it doesn not make a big difference, file_get_contents tooks 12 seconds, curl tooks 9 seconds

Answer (score 1):

Make a feature out of it :D - Load it asynchronously via ajax

(wont work here cause [SOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) - but you get the concept ;) )

If you are brave you can perform a loop of all 84 and load them at once - but this will get you unwanted attention pretty fast :P

```js
var i = 1;
var max = 82;
var sum = 0;

function load( i ) {
  $('#status').text( "Loading " + i + " of " + max );
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://secim-api.adilsecim.net/2/city/' + i + '.json',
    type: 'JSON',
    success: function(msg) {
      sum += msg.results.mi;
      
      if( i < 82 ) {
        load(i++);
      } else {
        $('#status').text( "Loading " + i + " of " + max + " DONE" );
      }
    }
  });
}

load(i);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<small><span id="status"></span><br/></small>
<br/>
Result: <span id="result">0</span>
```

Comment: that is a good idea but still it takes too much time, people don't want to wait